# How to change all my value with onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the value of the buttons with the first button, but nothing seems to work. I tried with many different codes like changeText, Myfunction1,2,3,4 etc and nothing worked... I'd be grateful if you help me.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Afinador de Violão</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/content.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <center>
      <marquee width="400px" scrollamount="10">Afinador V1.0</marquee></center>
      <CENTER>
        <input type="button" id="-" onclick="change()" value="bemol">
      </CENTER>
      <div id="content">
     <input name="1" type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="E" id="1" class="cordas"><br>
     <input name="2" type="button" onclick="myFunction2()" value="B" id="2" class="cordas"><br>
     <input name="3" type="button" onclick="myFunction3()" value="G" id="3" class="cordas"><br>
     <input name="4" type="button" onclick="myFunction4()" value="D" id="4" class="cordas"><br>
     <input name="5" type="button" onclick="myFunction5()" value="A" id="5" class="cordas"><br>
     <input name="6" type="button" onclick="myFunction6()" value="E" id="6" class="cordas"><br>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zepto.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/playsound.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function change(elem){
    var elem = document.getElementById("1");
    if (elem.value=="E") elem.value += "\u266D";
    else elem.value = "E";
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** I inserted the wrong code, look at this.

Comment: Please post your code (as *text*) in the question, don't just link to, or otherwise post, a *picture* of your code and expect that to be of any use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function, but you're not calling it. Try changing the `onclick()` to `change()` and selecting the element using this, (as a parameter).

```js
function change(elem) {
  if (elem.value == "E") elem.value += "\u266D";
  else elem.value = "E";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Afinador de Violão</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/content.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <marquee width="400px" scrollamount="15">Afinador V1.0</marquee>
  </center>
  <CENTER>
    c
  </CENTER>
  <div id="content">
    <input name="1" type="button" onclick="change(this)" value="E" id="1" class="cordas"><br>
    <input name="2" type="button" onclick="change(this)" value="B" id="2" class="cordas"><br>
    <input name="3" type="button" onclick="change(this)" value="G" id="3" class="cordas"><br>
    <input name="4" type="button" onclick="change(this)" value="D" id="4" class="cordas"><br>
    <input name="5" type="button" onclick="change(this)" value="A" id="5" class="cordas"><br>
    <input name="6" type="button" onclick="change(this)" value="E" id="6" class="cordas"><br>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, simply say

```
$('1').val('E\u266D');
```

to set the value. If you don't know the value, you can use

```
$('1').val($('1').val() + '\u266D');
```